# What could be causing this iOS MediaPlayer crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, media-player

We've received some crash reports with stack traces that are difficult for us to decipher. The stack trace is entirely within MediaPlayer, Foundation, CoreFoundation and libsystem_c.dylib. Unfortunately we haven't been able to reproduce on any of our development devices so troubleshooting is proving problematic.

Here's an example of the stack trace. Has anyone seen anything like this or have any pointers of what could be causing this crash?

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fc47fe0
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000196a0624c localeconv_l
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000196a55d6c __vfprintf + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000196a73680 __v2printf + 588
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000196a0620c _vsnprintf + 304
4   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000196a06c58 snprintf_l + 24
5   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018462b01c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11584
6   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001846282a4 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 248
7   Foundation                     0x000000018546e448 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 172
8   Foundation                     0x000000018546e308 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 76
9   MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bf524 -[NSObject(MPLogDescription) MP_shortDescription] + 96
10  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bf598 -[AVPlayerItem(MPLogDescription) MP_shortDescription] + 72
11  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bde2c -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems] + 1316
12  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bd8a4 -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncItems] + 1452
13  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869becbc -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _updateCurrentItem] + 620
14  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869be61c -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems] + 3348
15  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bd8a4 -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncItems] + 1452
16  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869becbc -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _updateCurrentItem] + 620
17  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869be61c -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems] + 3348
18  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869bd8a4 -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncItems] + 1452
19  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869becbc -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _updateCurrentItem] + 620
20  MediaPlayer                    0x00000001869be61c -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems] + 3348
...
```

The stack trace continues for several hundred more repetitions of the last three lines above.

Comment: Hi Greg, were you able to find a solution to this problem? This crash is currently happening to me as well and I'm trying to diagnose.

Comment: Any update guys ? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm fighting this exact problem in our app. To get it to consistently do this, try putting the device to sleep with the sleep button, then wake it up and then perform the action to cause the video to play. It happens every time here.

Comment: @greg I was able to have this error occur while plugged into development. It's breaking in the prepareToPlay method with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Granted, the video I'm doing this with is pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this happen on my iOS 8.4 app here.  Turns out that the App was trying to load an non-existing local video file.  It was trying to load 'Animation.mp4' when the file was called 'Intro.mp4' and I had no error catching code to detect this.

The end result was exactly the same stack trace as above - the several hundred repetitions of the last 3 lines of the trace, white screen and an App crash

So might be worth checking this - it might help someone, though hopefully you're a bit more sensible and have some error catching code around your loading code :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like the player enters into an infinite loop which either allocates memory or increases a pointer. This is (guessing here) most likely due to the loading of a malformated video file.

When the application runs out of addressable space and/or the pointer gets increased/decreased to a point where it points outside of the application's address space, the Kernel kills it for a memory violation.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same issue yesterday. I was tring to load video in MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
//Streaming video plying on MPMoviePlayerViewController

NSString *fileURL = @"http://...../myvideo.mp4";

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

 mpViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

        // Present the movie player view controller
        [self presentViewController:mpViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        // Start playback
        [mpViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

After running this I am getting following error
-[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems]

After spending hour I found bug :) my code. I was passing URL in "fileURLWithPath" because of that it's show that erro. To resolve that I just replace

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL];
```

with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];
```